# Carthageで導入したAlamofireが利用できない

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, alamofire

以下の記事を参考にCarthageでAlamofireを導入したのですが、ビルド時にエラーが出ます。
https://qiita.com/yutat93/items/97fe9bc2bf2e97da7ec1

ソースコードは生成してほぼそのままで、Alamofireだけimportしております。
また、Xcode9.3 Swift4.1を使用しています。

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

print("Hello, World!")
```

エラー内容は以下の通りです。

```
Environment variable not set: FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

よろしくお願いします。

※追加画像
[image: Run Scriptの設定内容]

*この質問は以下のサイトにもマルチポストしております。解決した場合は情報共有いたします。*
https://teratail.com/questions/120086

Comment: `copy-frameworks`の記述が間違ってますね。その手順のところで追加した設定を見せてください。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/120086

Comment: なるほど...只今画像を追加いたしました。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。お恥ずかしながら、マルチポストという言葉を初めて知りました...。今後は双方のURLを互い違いに記載した上で、片方で解決した場合、もう一方のサイトにも必ず情報共有いたします。

Answer (score 1):

解決いたしましたので報告します。

まず、リンク先の方法ではなく、cocoapodsを利用した方法を採用したところ、問題なく導入できました。

詳しくは、以下のリンクを参照してください。

https://www.appcoda.com/macos-image-uploader-app/